# Use an Input to hide and show divs of a specific class name and only that one class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a group of checkboxes that correspond to a group of images. When a input is checked, only those images with the corresponding class should appear. And not all the images that may have that class with other classes.

For example,

Some images have the class cloud, while others may have cloud and data, cloud, data, and networking and so sort. When I check cloud, only the images with cloud should appear. When I check cloud and data, only those images with cloud and data should appear.

This is what I've tried to add an active class to my checkboxes. That part works as I need to highlight them

```
$('.posts-filter input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
  // Audit all checkboxes on/off state

   let picked = $('.posts-filter input[type=checkbox]:checked') // <-- just get the checked ones
   // Somehow, extract just the "id" from just the checked elements
   // picked = ['cloud', 'network', 'data'];
   let specificTech;
   for (let i = 0; i < picked.length; i++){
    specificTech = picked[i].name;
   }
$(this).parent().toggleClass('active');

 })
```

The Checkbox:

```
                  <aside class="filter cell small-12 large-8">
                    <span class="label">Technologies</span>
                    <div class="posts-filter">
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label cloud">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="cloud">
                                <?php cloud_svg(); ?>
                                Cloud
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label data">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="data">
                                <?php data_svg(); ?>
                                Data Protection & Data Management
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label networking">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="networking">
                                <?php networking_svg(); ?>
                                Networking
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label security">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="security">
                                <?php security_svg(); ?>
                                Security
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label storage">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="storage">
                                <?php storage_svg(); ?>
                                Storage
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="posts-filter__sub">
                            <label class="posts-filter__label virtualization">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="virtualization">
                                <?php virtualization_svg(); ?>
                                Virtualization
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </aside>
```

The Images:

```
<a class="partner cloud data security" href="http://www.ca.com/" target="_blank"><img width="70" height="70" src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Image-7.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt=""></a>

<a class="partner cloud" href="http://www.ca.com/" target="_blank"><img width="70" height="70" src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Image-7.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: I think you may want to use a multiselect instead of checboxes. That way you can get an array of values from one input element, instead of searching for selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values of your checkboxes match the classes you want to select, you can construct a selector from them.  You said you want if multiple are selected, that the results should have **all** the values, that means a logical **and** conditional for the selectors.

```js
$(document.body).on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
  var $checkedCheckboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
  
  if ($checkedCheckboxes.length) {
    var classesSelector = '.'+ $checkedCheckboxes.get().map(it=>it.value).join('.');
    console.log(classesSelector);
  } else {
    console.log('no elements selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="cloud">
  Cloud
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="data">
  Data
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="network">
  Network
</label>
```